# Is it possible to pop a command from the \@preamblecmds list?

Tags: macros, preamble

Is it possible to pop a command from the `\@preamblecmds` list? The use case I have in mind is to allow `\DeclareMathOperator` to be used after the preamble.

Comment: yes it is just a list of csnames, but of course some commands won't actually work after begin document so you have to be careful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to take care as some commands are restricted as basically they would not work after `\begin{document}` but mostly they are removed to save a few bytes which was a major concern in 1994 but perhaps less so now:

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\let\zzz\@preamblecmds
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\@preamblecmds\zzz
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\DeclareMathOperator\foo{BAR}

$\foo x$

\end{document}
```

Comment: More generally, is it possible to pop from the `\@preamblecmds` list just a given command?

Comment: Yes, but for example \DeclareMathOperator if you just "save" that one fails as it uses some internal commands that have been removed, I started to see exactly what trail of commands needs to be popped but honestly it isn't worth it, just keep the lot:-)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé See my approach, but as David says there is a bigger issue here

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove an item from a list of tokens you need an appropriate auxiliary to do the removal. This can be set up a few ways, but perhaps the most straight-forward is first to check if the content is there at all then to remove it if it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\@tempa#1\do\DeclareMathOperator#2\nil{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax
  \else
    \def\@tempa##1\do\DeclareMathOperator##2\nil{\def\@preamblecmds{##1##2}}%
    \expandafter\@tempa\@preamblecmds\nil
  \fi
}
\expandafter\@tempa\@preamblecmds\do\DeclareMathOperator\nil
%\show\@preamblecmds
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}
```

The plan here is simple: check if `\do\DeclareMathOperator` is in `\@preamblecmds` and if it is split the rest of the tokens off and re-save them. In the case in point [David's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223423) may well be preferable as there are other commands that might also be involved (`\do\@declmathop` is also added to `\@preamblecmds`.)

---

We could generalise the above but I'd just use `expl3`, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\tl_remove_all:Nn \@preamblecmds { \do \DeclareMathOperator }
\tl_remove_all:Nn \@preamblecmds { \do \@declmathop }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\show\@preamblecmds
```

(I could use `\tl_remove_once:Nn` here as there is a single occurrence: not really a big issue either way.) Note that I need both `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\makeatletter` here to access the correct names.

Comment: You could of course generalise the above, which is much what something like `\tl_remove_once:Nn` from `expl3` does (although the latter is robust against various edge cases that the above isn't).

Comment: I would be very interested in the `expl3` way of doing it! ;)

Comment: Wow, much simpler! :)