# \setmathsfont can be used only in preamble

Tags: unicode-math, mathspec

Possibly related to

- [What is the difference between unicode-math and mathspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118244/what-is-the-difference-between-unicode-math-and-mathspec/118273)
- [Change math font only in some parts of a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14570/change-math-font-only-in-some-parts-of-a-document)

Roughly speaking, I would like to know if it is possible to change math font as freely as I can change text font by `\fontspec`.

It seems `\setmathsfont` form `mathspec` is powerful but can be used only in preamble. On the other hand `\setmathfont` from `unicode-math` can be used everywhere but it is not as powerful as `\setmathsfont`.

For instance, the following document does not compile

```
% !TEX program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathspec}
\begin{document}
    $1+2=3$
    \setmathsfont(Digits){Zapfino}
    $1+2=3$
\end{document}
```

And the following document does compile.

```
% !TEX program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
    $1+2=3$
    \setmathfont[range=up/num]{Zapfino}
    $1+2=3$
\end{document}
```

So my questions are

- Is `\setmathfont` an alternative to `\setmathsfont`?

  - If so, what corresponds to `\setmathsfont(Digits)`, `\setmathsfont(Latin)`,  and `\setmathsfont(Greek)`?
- Is it possible to use `\setmathsfont` within the document? Just like `\setmathfont` and `\setmainfont`.
- Or, is there any better way to break photomath? (see below)

## Motivation

I am currently making some arithmetic exercise such as

[image]

It turns out that my students use [photomath](https://photomath.net/en/) to get the answer. The good news is that photomath does not recognize "ugly" fonts such as Zapfino.

[image]

But for demonstrating purpose, I want to use "pretty" font such as Latin Modern in the same document. So it would be nice if I can switch between "pretty" and "ugly" fonts.

Comment: for the 2nd question see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223421/is-it-possible-to-pop-a-command-from-the-preamblecmds-list

Comment: @touhami does not work (if I understood @David Carlisle's answer correctly.) It is `\DeclareSymbolFont` that is defined as `\@latex@error {Can be used only in preamble}\@eha`. Should I try @Joseph Wright♦'s answer instead?

Comment: Imho in the long run unicode-math is the saner way to setup math.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can take that :) I did not prefer either of them.