# How to change the math font for some "regular" font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

Relevant to those:

- [Change math font only in some parts of a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14570/change-math-font-only-in-some-parts-of-a-document)
- [\setmathsfont can be used only in preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284818/setmathsfont-can-be-used-only-in-preamble)
- https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30616

I'm trying to change the font at math-mode:
If it's with "s": `\setmathsfont` -  it doesn't compile, if it's without the "s: it's doesn't change the font...

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\[
a+b^{2}+5
\]

\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

Can you help to understand how to change the font at math-mode?

Thank you!!

Comment: you can not use Arial as the main math font using unicode-math, `\setmathfont` requires an OpenType Math font (that is the font has an internal MATH table giving math typesetting layout parameters)

Comment: Arial is a text font, not a math font.

Comment: And `\setmathsfont` is defined by the `mathspec` package, but not the `unicode-math` package.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!! @DavidCarlisle - Those fonts are good? https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html

Comment: not all of them I think, I believe there is an answer here that listed the opentype math fonts available at the time, I'll see if I can find.

Comment: there is this answer but that;s 2014 more are available now it could be updated.... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219392/state-of-unicode-math-typesetting-fonts

Comment: @DavidCarlisle https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available

Comment: @Davislor thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change it in one section, and be able to change back, declare a math version.

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setsansfont{Fira GO}
\setmathfont[version=sans]{Fira Math}
```

Then in the document:

```
\sffamily\mathversion{sans}
```

If you want to be able to use Arial letters with your math font, but do not need to switch between different math fonts, use the `range=` option.

```
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont[range=up]{Arial}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Arial Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup]{Arial Bold}
\setmathfont[range=bfit]{Arial Bold Italic}
```

Alternatively, you can load `mathastext`.

Unfortunately, the `range=` and `version=` options of `\setmathfont` do not work together (as of 2019}, so you cannot switch to and from a math version with Arial letters.

Comment: And it must be something with math support ? I.e, from here: https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html

Comment: @heblyx That’s a list of legacy 8-bit fonts. You wouldn’t use them with `unicode-math`, but you could load them with `mathspec`.

Comment: @heblyx A font that you use with `\setmathfont[version=...` must have [OpenType math support.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) A math font that you load with `\setmathfont[range=...` need only contain whatever glyphs are in that range.